# Find Element in Array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if there is a certain value in an array of objects.

For example, if I have something like this:

```
[ { _id: 1,    
    name: foo },
  { _id: 2,    
    name: bar },
    { _id: 3,    
    name: foox },
    { _id: 4,    
    name: fooz },
    ]


var search = [1,25,33,4,22,44,5555,63]
```

then I want to check if one of the values in `search` is in one of the objects contained in the array of objects.

Comment: Also, what are you checking the search array against? The ids?

Comment: yes, i don't know if i have to cycle the search or the object...i try with http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/find

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = [ { _id: 1, name: "foo" },
  { _id: 2, name: "bar" },
  { _id: 3, name: "foox" },
  { _id: 4, name: "fooz" },
];


var search = [1,25,33,4,22,44,5555,63];

list.forEach(function(element){
    if(search.indexOf(element._id) != -1){
        console.log("found");
    }
});
```

Try this, hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to iterate over the array of objects. If an id is found `some` short-circuits and doesn't continue with the rest of the iteration.

```js
const data=[{_id:1,name:'foo'},{_id:2,name:'bar'},{_id:3,name:'foox'},{_id:4,name:'fooz'}];
const search = [1,25,33,4,22,44,5555,63]

function finder(searh) {
  return data.some(obj => {
    return search.includes(obj._id);
  });
}

console.log(finder(data, search));
```

Answer (score 0):

if:

```
var o = [{ _id: 1, name: "foo"}, { _id: 2, name: "bar"}, { _id: 3, name: "foox"}, { _id: 4, name: "fooz"}];
var search = [1, 25, 33, 4, 22, 44, 5555, 63];
```

try this:

```
var outPus = o.filter(function(u){ 
    return search.some(function(t){ return t == u._id}) 
})
```

or this:

```
var outPut = [];
search.forEach(function(u){ 

    o.forEach(function(t){ 

        if(t._id == u) outPut.push(t) 
    }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [ { _id: 1,    
    name: foo },
  { _id: 2,    
    name: bar },
    { _id: 3,    
    name: foox },
    { _id: 4,    
    name: fooz },
    ];

var isAnyOfIdsInArrayOfObject = function(arrayOfObjects, ids){
   return arrayOfObjects.some(function(el) { return ids.indexOf(el._id) !== -1; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [ 
  { _id: 1, name: 'foo' },
  { _id: 2, name: 'bar' },
  { _id: 3, name: 'foox' },
  { _id: 4, name: 'fooz' }
];

var search = [1,25,33,4,22,44,5555,63];
```

This code builds a list of all the elements in `search` that are also in your `list`:

```
var inArr = search.filter(function(index){
  return list.some(function(el){
    return el._id === index;
  });
});
console.log(inArr); // [1,4];
```

Obviously you can switch the `list` and `search` around so you get an array with the elements from `list` that are referenced in `search`:

```
var elements = list.filter(function(el){
  return search.some(function(index){
    return el._id === index;
  });
});
console.log(elements); // [{ _id: 1, name: 'foo' },{ _id: 4, name: 'fooz' }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example of find method. Hope this will help you.

```
   // sample item array
   const items = [
                   { name : 'Bike', price : 100 },
                   { name : 'Car',  price : 3000 }
                 ]
   // find method example
   const foundItem = items.find(( item )) => {
         // you can put your desired condition over here to find an element from 
         // javascript array.
         return item.name == 'Bike'
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A limitation of forEach loops is that you cannot return the found element from your (outer) method.   Instead you can use **Array.prototype.find** as follows:

```
var elt = list.find(e => search.indexOf(e._id)>=0);
if (!elt)
    console.log("Element not found");
else
    console.log("Found element " + elt.name);
```

Note: This will require a polyfill for Array.prototype.find in IE.